# Angular Emit Parent Child Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-2-dg6wag?file=main.ts

with the above example the (click)="toggleSideBar()" in side-bar.component.ts will not close the side bar

any ideas?

Comment: That code does not exist in the site you've linked. Don't link to your code on a separate site. Put a COMPLETE sample of your problem directly in the question. That's why there are tools for both runnable code snippets and formatted code blocks in the editor

Comment: yes it does  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-2-dg6wag?file=app%2Fside-bar%2Fside-bar.component.html

Comment: no it doesn't you're linking to the WHOLE project in your question. you can't say "yes it does", then link to a completely different file. No one here is going to help you if you can't even put enough effort in to put your problem code in your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two `app-side-bar` so even if one was hidden one was always visible. Try this in you app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  app component
  <br>
  <br>

  <app-side-bar [isOpen]="sideBarIsOpened" (toggle)="toggleSideBar()"></app-side-bar>

  <br>
  <br>

  <button (click)="toggleSideBar()">Toggle sidebar from app component</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances of your sidebar in your html.  Imagine this code ([link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-2-jeciep?file=app/app.component.html)) which is your code with styles for each element added:

```
  <app-side-bar 
    [isOpen]="sideBarIsOpened" 
    (toggle)="toggleSideBar()" 
    style="background-color: blue"></app-side-bar>
  <app-side-bar 
    [isOpen]="sideBarIsOpened"
    style="background-color: red"></app-side-bar>
```

You can only see the red one, the second one.  That's because they are both positioned the same and it appears later in the html.  The problem is you only have `(click)="toggleSideBar()"` on the first one, which is hidden by the second.  When the red one emits this event, the app component isn't listening for it.  When you click the button on the app component, it sets the flag wich *both* of them use, so they both get hidden or displayed...

You probably only want [one sidebar](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-2-sph7at?file=app/app.component.html), right?  If not, then please explain what you are trying to achieve...